# Textbook suggestions for in-depth treatment of dirac delta function

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, electromagnetism

I am looking for textbook suggestions for studying the dirac delta function and relation distribution functions in detail. The level could be upper undergrad or graduate level, I have studied this in my previous courses but I am looking to study it in detail to understand the mathematical motivation for it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can read french, I believe "Théorie des Distributions" by Schwartz is still a valuable reference.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot read French. I am a novice learner now, I want to read Euler in French. Is there perhaps a translation of Schwartz's work? Also, if I downloaded it, do you think I can follow the mathematics without actually fully understanding what is being said? Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

Kolmogorov and Fomin's *Introductory Real Analysis* does a nice job introducing the ideas with the rigor of distributions in their section on Generalized Functions. This book is also a nice introduction to functional analysis.

Another place you might look, for a more general, in-depth, and measure theoretic perspective, is Folland's *Real Analysis*, chapter 3.

Comment: Cool, I'll give those a look. I hadn't considered a measure theoretic approach to formulating distribution functions, that is pretty interesting.